# reload rails environment after migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, reload

I have a few data migrations which define models. For example:

`db/migrate/19600000000000_some_migration.rb`:

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # operations requiring the Step class
  end
end
```

and when I run seeds right after migrations

```
rake db:migrate db:seed
```

the redefined `Step` class is still in memory. But I need the `Step` class that is originally defined in `app/models/step.rb` because my seeds rely on a method there, or else it silently fails.

There are a few things I can think of, but neither of them is ideal:

1. `require 'app/models/step.rb'` before seeding

   - this doesn't really work for me because it relies on another model that was also redefined in a migration, which could turn into a rabbit hole.
2. `Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load(f) }`

   - I don't love this, either, because it is redefining constants
3. Always run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed` separately

I've tried looking for ways to reload the entire environment after seeding, but neither of them seems to work:

- `ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!`
- `Rack::Reloader.new(MyApp).reload!`

Any thoughts on what the most scalable approach would be?

Comment: Run they separately in line: `rake db:migrate && rake db:seed`

Comment: Too you can try this: `Step.connection.schema_cache.clear!
Step.reset_column_information`

Comment: I recommend use raw sql for changing data in migration or use rake tasks for changing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def change
    # operations requiring the Step class
  end
end
```